# When does Windows change a files access time over share?

Tags: windows, internals

Each file has a specific creation time, last written time and last access time.
I was wondering: When does Windows change the files "last access time"? Only when I open the file? Maybe when Windows shows it's Icon(lets say I have a shortcut the the file...)?

Moreover - what about shares? if I have a file in a share and more than one computer accesses it - how does windows determines the last access time? On which of the users clock?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access time is maintained by the system serving the files. It is written after you do any operation with the opened file.

Since access time is [not maintained](http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2006/11/07/disabling-last-access-time-in-windows-vista-to-improve-ntfs-performance.aspx) on modern Windows versions anyways, your programs should ignore it.

Comment: Thanks - what about exe's(on older Windows versions, such as Windows XP)? If I open a program - does it change its last access time? (I assume thats the case..)

Comment: Yes, executing a file is another form of opening it.

Comment: I also noted that this time may change if the program is already open - during the work... how it's possible?

Comment: It's a last *access* time, so any reading or writing to the file can update it.

Comment: You're right - but the file's mapped to the memory when I open it in the first place - why would Windows read it again?

Comment: MindBlower The memory mapping doesn't have to be backed up by actual memory. So when you read a location inside the mapped area, Windows may read from the file. I suspect your problem is something else and not actually related to Windows internals. Or, to phrase it differently: Why do you care about access time? It's basically a low-entropy source of randomness, and has nothing to do with the actual last access time of the file.

Comment: Actually thats a question I got asked today at an interview. I thought I knew the answer, but the interviewer said that it is more complicated than I stated - just interesting :)

Thanks!